# Office 365 SharePoint CSOM search navigation

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, navigation

I am trying to find if that is possible to change site's **search navigation**(a.k.a search dropdown links) through CSOM?

Seems Search's export configuration does not contain info about search navigation(Site Settings->Search->Search Settings), and i am struggling to find any article that describes whether this is doable through CSOM.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The node id for site navigation is 1040, so:
i use this for clear all site navigation nodes from a site:

```
NavigationNodeCollection lNodes = ctx.Web.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040).Children;
ctx.Load(lNodes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

lNodes.ToList().ForEach(node => node.DeleteObject());
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

this is to delete some existing node navigation by its title:

```
NavigationNodeCollection lNodes = ctx.Web.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040).Children;
ctx.Load(lNodes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

NavigationNode lNode = lNodes.ToList().Find(node => node.Title.Equals(this.Title));
lNode.DeleteObject();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

this is to add some new node navigation:

```
NavigationNodeCollection lNodes = ctx.Web.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040).Children;
ctx.Load(lNodes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

NavigationNodeCreationInformation nnci = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
nnci.Url = "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/";
nnci.Title = "SharePoint";
nnci.AsLastNode = true;

NavigationNode lNode = lNodes.Add(nnci);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Please provide context for links and quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Ok, I totally agree with your comments and edit the post with reference to my code. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think these settings are all set through the Property bag. Try setting some stuff in the UI then inspect the property bag for that web.

Here's an old article I wrote years ago about how to do this: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Making-use-of-the-Property-Bag-in-the-ECMAScript-Client-Object-Model.aspx

(in short, in case the link dies one day, use Web.get_allProperties() then cycle through the result, or use get_item('key_name') to get a value out).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately could not find anything in the property bag after setting few navigation links for search. will post answer here if i find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few months old, but I ran into this myself recently and documented the solution here: http://sharepointtaproom.com/2015/02/17/missing-searchnav-property-in-sharepoint-client-object-model/

In server-side code, you'd use the SPNavigation.SearchNav property to customize the search menu. However, the client-side object model doesn't include that property. Instead, you have to access a special "search root" node as documented in the blog post I linked to and add/remove child nodes to/from that root node to customize the menu.

I used that approach recently to write a scheduled job in Windows Azure that copies search navigation settings from a parent site to all the child sites in my collection (since SharePoint 2013 doesn't let child sites inherit search navigation settings, unfortunately). Since the job was hosted in Azure, I had to use the client object model to accomplish this.

Comment: Link is not working...